# is it the only way to use express.static?

Tags: node.js, express, static

i'm developing web site like below

```
webpage
    -app
        -routers
            -photo.js
    -public
        -css
            -photo.css
        -views
            -photo.ejs
    -server.js
```

when i connect to **localhost:3000/photo** i had no problem.
but, when i connect to **localhost:3000/photo/hero** i couldn't get css
so, i add this three line

```
app.use('/photo/4din2d',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/photo/tree',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/photo/hero',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

this is problem, i'm going to add more category like **'hero, tree, 4din2d'**
and i think add express.static everytime is not a good way. please give me the right way.

photo.js

> `router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
>           res.render('photo');
>       });
>       router.get('/:id',(req,res)=>{
>         var category = req.params.id;
>          res.render('photo');
>       });`

photo.ejs

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/photo.css">
```

server.js

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/photo',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/photo/4din2d',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/photo/tree',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/photo/hero',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    var photo = require('./app/routers/photo.js');
    app.use('/photo',photo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **server.js**, you only need the one static directory, **public**:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Then in **photo.ejs**, you should reference your assets relative to the root (**/**) rather than relative to the current route (**./**):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/photo.css">
```

I hope this helps.